# $P/P^2$ isomorphic to $R/P$ as $R$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $P$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. When is it true that $P^n/P^{n+1}$ are isomorphic to $R/P$ as $R$-modules for any $n$? I was trying to show that for Dedekind domains the norm of ideals is a multiplicative function. I found a proof of this on page 26 of these [lecture notes](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~frederique/antchap2.pdf), which seems to imply that this is true for any ring and any prime ideal.

Is this true in general? I was considering this example: $R = k[x]/(x^2), P = (x)/(x^2)$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Then $P^2/P^3$ seems to be the zero $R$-module but $R/P$ is non-zero...

Comment: I think you want to say "Let $P$ be a *prime* ideal". In your example $P^2=0$, and thus $P^n=0$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not going to be true in general. Consider $R = k[x,y]$ and $P =(x,y)$. Then $R/P \cong k$ that is a field but $P/P^2 \cong (x,y)/(x^2,xy, y^2)$ that is two dimensional over $k$.

More generally we see that $P^d/P^{d+1}$ is isomorphic to the space of homogeneous forms of degree $d$ in $x$ and $y$. Thus $\dim_k P/P^2 =d + 1$ and so $P/P^2$ is not going to be isomorphic to $k$ for any $d$.

Comment: I think that even though $k$ and $(x,y)/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ are not isomorphic as $k$-modules, they are still isomorphic as $k[x,y]$-modules.

Comment: @bob What is an isomorphism of $k[x,y]$ modules? First of all it's a group isomorphism between $R/P$ and $P/P^2$. Second it's compatible with $k[x,y]$ multiplication. Now if it's compatible with $k[x,y]$ multiplication then certainly it's compatible with $k$ multiplication. But then this means that $R/P$  and $P/P^2$ are isomorphic as $k$ - modules which is impossible.

Comment: So this is true for Dedekind domains?Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: @awllower Yes that is correct. In my example above $k[x,y]$ is not a Dedekind domain because not non-zero every prime ideal is maximal.